# Basic iframe Not Loading One Webpage

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to load an iframe for an ESPN fantasy league into a website I made for our league members.  I can load pretty much any page I want except for this one, which is a link right to our league.

```
<iframe src="https://games.espn.go.com/flb/leagueoffice?leagueId=27520&seasonId=2015" name="grforum" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center" height = "100%" width = "100%">
```

Any idea what could be causing this or how I would be able to get it to load?  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you open up your JavaScript console, you'll see that the web page (ESPN) does not permit cross-origin framing - i.e. they don't allow you to load that within an iframe on your website.

> Load denied by X-Frame-Options: http://games.espn.go.com/flb/leagueoffice?leagueId=27520&seasonId=2015 does not permit cross-origin framing.